# GridView only shows first row

Tags: android, gridview

i have a gridview to show images with button, but i have a problem, it only shows the first row, and i send it data for 3 rows..

This is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- To make screen scroll in vertical direction -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bootstrapthumbnail="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/fondodroid2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Main layout -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fefdff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/login_activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/login_activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin"
                android:padding="@dimen/login_activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:baselineAligned="true"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/login_activity_logo"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/login_activity_logo"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:src="@drawable/logo"
                        android:contentDescription="Icon GG"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="@string/files"
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/login_activity_text"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="#686868"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:text="@string/sign_string"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/linearSign"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="#cccccc"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/sign_thumb"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:layout_margin="3dp"></ImageView>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/sign_thumb"
                            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/sign_thumb">

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Eliminar"
                                android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
                                android:background="#cc6b67"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>


                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="#686868"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:text="@string/images"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">


                    <GridView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/gridImages"
                        android:numColumns="2"
                        android:layerType="hardware"
                        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
                        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/login_activity_logo_h"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/login_activity_logo_v"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin"
                android:contentDescription="@string/logo" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the adapter i dont have any strangle, but if you need i copy it here..I try with fill_parent wrap_content etc but nothing works..

Edit: the adapter code:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Activity activity;
    private List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
    private OnDeleteItem mListener;

    public interface OnDeleteItem {
        public void onDeleteItemClick(String path);
    }

    public GridAdapter(Activity inyectActivity, List<String> listImages) {
        activity = inyectActivity;
        images = listImages;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        mListener = (ReviewFilesActivity) activity;

    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged(List<String> dataImages) {
        images = dataImages;
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GridViewHolder vHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view, null);
            vHolder = new GridViewHolder(convertView, mListener);
            vHolder.image.setImageBitmap(ImagesUtilities.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(images.get(position), 400, 400));
            vHolder.path = images.get(position);
            vHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mListener.onDeleteItemClick(images.get(position));
                }
            });
        } else {
            vHolder = (GridViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    static class GridViewHolder {

        public GridViewHolder(View view, OnDeleteItem listener) {
            ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
        }

        @InjectView(R.id.grid_item_image)
        ImageView image;
        @InjectView(R.id.deleteButton)
        Button delete;
        String path;

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }

    }
}
```

Edit2:

I did more simply the XML, but the rows dont show.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- To make screen scroll in vertical direction -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/fondodroid2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Main layout -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fefdff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/login_activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/login_activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin"
                android:padding="@dimen/login_activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:baselineAligned="true"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/login_activity_logo"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/login_activity_logo"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:src="@drawable/logo"
                        android:contentDescription="Icon GG"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="@string/files"
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/login_activity_text"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:text="@string/sign_string"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:background="#686868"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/sign_thumb"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Eliminar"
                        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
                        android:background="#cc6b67"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:text="@string/images"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:background="#686868"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

                    <GridView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/gridImages"
                        android:numColumns="2"
                        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
                        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />
                </RelativeLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/login_activity_logo_h"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/login_activity_logo_v"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_activity_vertical_margin"
                android:contentDescription="@string/logo" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: adapter code would be helpful

Comment: Your layout is overcomplicated, I doubt you really need so much nested linear layouts and relative layouts. My first hint would be that your gridview's height it's match parent, but there's not enough room to show it, and the (far) outer scollview's child has a height of match parent too, so the scrolling doesn't work.

Comment: I will edit it to do it more simply..

Comment: @rekaszeru i did it more simply but with the same result

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simplified example to achieve needed layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sign_thumb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_icon" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridImages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```